# WAMP: Viewing Virtual Host site from phone

Tags: apache, web, wamp, virtualhost, server

I've recently learned how to setup Virtual Sites with WAMP by following this [***Tutorial***](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-setup-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/).

I've tried viewing the server through my phone by typing my ip address in the browsers address bar but am being told I am forbidden to access it.

I've read a few things online that can help solve this but can't seem to understand what they mean. One advise was to root the phone so that I can access its hosts file, but I understand that'll stop my phone from updating important software. And another is setting up my own server, which I don't know how to do, which also doesn't explain how.

Is there anything I can do within the Apache httpd.conf file or anything else that can help me view my virtual site(s)?

Comment: Are you able to access `http://localhost` on server?

Comment: I can through my computer because I set that up as a virtual server as well. From my phone unfortunately I can't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with is to create another VirtualHost with a port number, which I can view from my ip-address.

In the **httpd.conf** file I wrote,

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www\mysite'
    <Directory 'C:\wamp\www\mysite'>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from ::1
        Allow from localhost
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 90
```

Now when I type `IP-ADDRESS:PORTNUMBER` in a remote web browser connected to my wifi, I can view the site.

I've written a blog about it [**HERE**](http://www.joshuawaheed.co.uk/blog/setup-virtual-hosts-with-wamp/).